# What would be the probability density function for a Monte Carlo sampling strategy which only samples a single value?

Tags: statistics, computer-science, monte-carlo

*Please see my edit for a more concise description of my question*

Ever since I started looking into the mathematics behind path-tracing algorithms, there has been one question that I haven't been able to find an answer to: How are deterministic samples weighted in an importance sampled Monte Carlo estimation? By deterministic samples, I mean values that will *ALWAYS* be sampled, as opposed to values which are sampled probabilistically. In importance sampling, non-uniform sampling can be achieved without introducing any bias, by dividing the value of a sample by it's probability of being chosen from a given distribution function. Deterministic samples can't be represented in a probability distribution function, since they are inherently non-probabilistic.

My question is: if a specific value or range of values are always sampled, how are they weighted in order to not introduce statistical bias?

This is a core mathematical principal behind path-tracing, as samples which connect vertices of a path, which is probabilistically drawn, to light sources are always sampled, in order to reduce variance. This is somehow done without introducing statistical bias, yet I cannot find any information on how this is achieved.

**EDIT:** I have done some more research, and gotten closer to the answer, yet some question still remain.

After reading [this paper on Multiple Importance Sampling](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348b-03/papers/veach-chapter9.pdf), I have discovered the *combined sample density function*:

[image: formula]

here "n" represents the number of sampling strategies used, "
[image: formula]" the fraction of samples taken with strategy k, and "[image: formula]" being the probability distribution function of strategy k.

**MY REMAINING QUESTION IS:** What would be the probability density function ([image: formula]) for a sampling strategy which only samples a single value? It can't be infinite, otherwise path-tracing algorithms could not handle point, or purely directional light sources, as directly sampling them would contribute an infinitely small amount towards the final estimation of radiance.

Comment: For people trying to answer this: the user cross-posted this also to the CG stack. They are trying to apply numerical methods to an integral with a dirac delta. The obvious answer is to handle the dirac delta in the continuous setting still and apply numerical methods only after it has been removed. It's also what is done in computer graphics/light transport.